# Ubuntu 16.04 installation in WSL reports itself as 'bionic''

Tags: 16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed 16.04 from the Microsoft Store using WSL and the installed Ubuntu version reports itself as Bionic.

```bsh
user@host:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Also, `apt` is configured to fetch software from the `bionic` distribution.

```bsh
user@host:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

# ...
```

Anyone knows what may be going on?

See [related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4068) in the WSL Github repo.

Comment: Either you installed 18.04 by mistake or a Microsoft Store bug I guess

Comment: I installed 16.04, I already triple-checked, and I'm not the only one with this problem. I guess it must be a Store bug, but clicking the support button on the store page for Ubuntu 16.04 brings me to this site, that's why I ask here.

Comment: I didn't have this problem 6 months ago so I'd file a bug report if I were you.

Comment: Me neither on a previous installation, so it must be a relatively recent problem. Where do you suggest I file the bug report, though?

Comment: Well so what we need to figure out is if it's *really* 18.04 or if it just *says* 18.04

Comment: In addition to the output of lsb_release, the apt repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list are all pointing to the bionic distribution. Anything else I should check?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [it was a bug after all](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4068#issuecomment-496681232), and Canonical is reverting the 16.04 app to a previous version until the new one passes the Store certification.